# How convert UClassProperty to TSublcassOf<> in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have struct property iterator and I need to handle TSubclassOf<> property.

I have a structure with a TSubclassOf<> variable named "ItemClass".
I managed to get FClassProperty, but I can't find a way to get the TSubclassOf variable out of it.

There is my code:

```
void UItemMaster::HandleStruct(FProperty* Property, void* StructPtr)
{
    int64 ItemHash = 0;
    TSubclassOf<UItemBase> ItemClass;

    FStructProperty* StructProperty = CastField<FStructProperty>(Property);
    if (StructProperty)
    {
        TFieldIterator<FProperty> PropertyIterator(StructProperty->Struct);
    
        for (PropertyIterator; PropertyIterator; ++PropertyIterator)
        {
            for (int32 ArrayIndex = 0; ArrayIndex < PropertyIterator->ArrayDim; ArrayIndex++)
            {
                void* ValuePtr = PropertyIterator->ContainerPtrToValuePtr<void>(StructPtr, ArrayIndex);

                if (PropertyIterator->GetAuthoredName() == TEXT("ItemClass"))
                {
                    if (FClassProperty* ClassProperty = CastField<FClassProperty>(*PropertyIterator))
                    {
                        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, *ClassProperty->GetName());
                        // here i need to convert ClassProperty to TSubclassOf<>

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I searched on the Internet, but found nothing useful.

I also created a unreal forum tread: [Unreal Engine Forum Link](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1825472-property-iteration)